# Python script to extract a javascript variable from html on a page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib, python-requests-html

I have the following javascript in the header of pages on my site:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var gaProperty = 'UA-00000000-1';
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
if ( document.cookie.indexOf( disableStr + '=true' ) > -1 ) {
window[disableStr] = true;
}
function gaOptout() {
document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
window[disableStr] = true;
}
</script>
```

Im trying to extract the **var gaProperty** from each page (i.e **UA-00000000-1**) in a list of url's in a csv file using python. Im new to python and put together a script from bits of scripts ive seen around but it doesnt work:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

list = []
with open('list.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        list.append(url) # Add each url to list contents
    

for url in list: 
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    path = " ".join(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    data = soup.find_all('script', type='text/javascript')
    gaid = re.search(r'UA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+', data[0].text)
    print(path, gaid)
```

The incorrect result i get is:

```
https:www.example.com/contact-us/ None
```

I need to achieve this desired output for each url:

```
https:www.example.com/contact-us/ UA-00000000-1
```

Any idea how to get this working in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I would include the var gaProperty in the pattern, to be more specific, then ensure the capture group is lazily capturing everything between the `'` that follow i.e. wrap the gaid value.

```
import re

html ='''
<script type='text/javascript'>
var gaProperty = 'UA-00000000-1';
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
if ( document.cookie.indexOf( disableStr + '=true' ) > -1 ) {
window[disableStr] = true;
}
function gaOptout() {
document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
window[disableStr] = true;
}
</script>'''

gaid = re.search(r"var gaProperty = '(.*?)'", html).group(1)
print(f'https:www.example.com/contact-us/{gaid}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesnt work. Remember, im scraping a list of urls from my csv file. The error i get is: TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'. Any ideas how to get it working with a list of urls?

Comment: You need to replace html with the content, as text, of the response from each request.